# Do I need MediaDevices permissions to take screenshots at intervals?

Tags: webrtc, webcam, mediadevices

Regarding the MediaDevices API.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

I know I need permission to use a media device to capture video, however I am not sure if I need to request permission multiple times in order to capture videoshots at regular intervals or just the one time at the start?

In other words, when does the permission expire? When the stream is closed, browser is refreshed or something else?

Can I use the initial permission to capture subsequent videoshots or do I need permission for each videoshot I intend to capture.

Comment: How are you taking screenshots?

Comment: Good question Inogueir :-D. See my answer below if still  interested.

Answer (score 1):

The browser continues to store the settings for device access, so you only need to approve it the first time. Unless you reset the settings yourself.

For example in chrome, you can check the permission of the site at the address below.

cam : `chrome://settings/content/camera`

mic :`chrome://settings/content/microphone`

Answer (score 0):

According to [getUserMedia docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

> First, getUserMedia() must always get user permission before opening any media gathering input such as a webcam or microphone. Browsers may offer a once-per-domain permission feature, but they must ask at least the first time, and the user must specifically grant ongoing permission if they choose to do so.

So we can see that the user must explicitly choose to grant the ongoing permission option from the pop-up, otherwise, it's going to ask every time.

The permissions pop-up and default selections may vary between browsers though, but they all support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I decided against using the native browser APIs directly, opting instead to use a service like Twillio to handle video capture AND recording. Once we have the recording I intend to chop it up to get a series of screen shots that summarize the video. This is not in realtime and does not need to be for my application.